# OAuth Error General Code 4 Swift - AppAuth for iOS

Tags: ios, swift, oauth-2.0, google-cloud-storage

Im trying to implement AppAuth in iOS. basic implementation has been done. seems to be everything working fine. but im not recieving the token as expected. im getting Error `Error Domain=org.openid.appauth.general Code=-4`

```
   let authorizationEndpoint : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth")!
    let tokenEndpoint : NSURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v4/token")!

    let configuration = OIDServiceConfiguration(authorizationEndpoint: authorizationEndpoint as URL, tokenEndpoint: tokenEndpoint as URL)

    let request  = OIDAuthorizationRequest.init(configuration: configuration, clientId: "<MyTOKEN>", scopes: [OIDScopeOpenID], redirectURL: URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:9004")!, responseType: OIDResponseTypeCode, additionalParameters: nil)

    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    //        appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow
    appDelegate.currentAuthorizationFlow = OIDAuthState.authState(byPresenting: request, presenting: self, callback: { (authState, error) in
        if((authState) != nil){
            print("Got authorization tokens. Access token: \(authState?.lastTokenResponse?.accessToken)")
        }else{
            print("Authorization error \(error?.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
```

Comment: did you set clientSecret with the request

Comment: Ah no. it wasnt mention in the document `https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS` how to do that?

Comment: found it in document but `client_secret The client secret obtained from the API Console. This value is not needed for clients registered as Android, iOS, or Chrome applications` since im using it for iOS its not needed right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dealing with errors and changes i figured out the problem after dealing with redirectUri and Token. 
`redirectUri` - once you authorized with google it will generate the token and after that you should open the app. redirectUri will help with that. 
This is how you can setup [redirectUri](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/Examples/README-Google.md)

`The value for iOS URL scheme wil be the scheme of your redirect URI. This is the Client ID in reverse domain name notation, e.g. com.googleusercontent.apps.IDENTIFIER. To construct the redirect URI, add your own path component. E.g. com.googleusercontent.apps.IDENTIFIER:/oauth2redirect/google. Note that there is only a single slash (/) after the scheme.`